# how to increase the contents size of a webview on iOS

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a webview to load a web page normal, only problem is that on the iphone the page looks very small. 
I wanted to ask if there is any method to increase the size of the content of the page but always remaining on the screen, as if it were always active with the zoom, but without having to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

No?

Maybe there's not enough detail in your question, but `UIWebView`, I believe by default, will try to scale its content to fit the size of the webview.  It should make the content as large as possible without the need for scrolling by default.

You can make the content larger by zooming in... but as it was already as large as possible without needing scrolling, as soon as you make it any larger, you will scroll.  The only way to view the content any larger is by having a bigger webview... and if your webview is already given the entirety of the screen, then the only solution is to get a device with a larger screen (there are currently 4 different screen size options for iOS devices).